# storing user uploaded image inside server path

Tags: java

I have a user form wherein a user can upload an image..I want to stor that image on Apache tomcat server..

I tried out a code like this.

```
 String filePath = getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") +"Images";

    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    outputStream.write(userForm.getUploadedFile().getFileData());
```

but its giving me FileNotFound Exception..I am unable to figure out what is the issue.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\aarti juno\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\NewStrutsOBL\Images (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
    at com.fulcrum.obl.Action.UserAction.addUser(UserAction.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:270)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fulcrum.obl.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

and the line on which it is giving error is  ---

```
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
```

Please guide on this..

Comment: dont test it from eclipse, using relative path

Comment: You must have already create folder "Images" inside your project folder...

Comment: yes, there is already a folder named "Images" in that path .. so why the problem? Instead it should write to that folder..right?

Comment: You might not use path separator... You can do directly... 

String filePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("Images");

Comment: it gives same Exception